# How can we store and retrieve a certificate containing private key in a windows store + C#

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, private-key

In my Windows application I will get a certificate containing private key. The public key is with me. I want to securely store this certificate in Windows secure folder and could be able to access this whenever required. Please help me to do this. Any sample program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for how can we store certificate with private key.

```
byte[] byteKey = DecodePrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoCertificateKey));
RSAParameters rsaParam = DecodeRSAPrivateKeyToRSAParam(byteKey);
                    var cspParams = new CspParameters
                    {
                        ProviderType = 1,
                        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseUserProtectedKey | CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt};
 using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite); 
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
                    {
                        rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
                        rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(cryptoCertificate, "123",
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
store.Add(x509Certificate);
}}
```

But I didn't get a solution that how to secure the privatekey with password